# Powers of complexes modulo a prime $p$

Tags: ring-theory, complex-numbers, integer-rings

We have, for a residue number system, $a^{n+(p-1)} \equiv a^n \bmod p$.  In other words, the powers of $a$ repeat after $p-1$ iterations.

We can work with complex numbers by representing a number $$n \equiv a (\bmod p) + bi (\bmod p)$$

...In other words, we can represent a complex number as two values modulo some prime $p$.  My question is:  **How many unique powers (or values) can there be of these complex numbers modulo a prime $p$?**

In other words, if we take the values $1, n, n^2, \dots$, how many unique values can we have, modulo $p$?

Comment: So, let me see if I understood well: are you working with numbers of the form $a+bi$ with $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Crostul:  Yes.  Then I want to take some number $n=a+bi$ to a power, so that I'd have $n^m$.  This should be $(a+bi)^m \bmod p$.  If I use the calculation $n^2 = (a^2-b^2) \bmod p + (2ab)i\bmod p$, for example, to calculate a power of $n$, how many unique values can I get?

Comment: Do you know the ring of Gaussian Integers and some of its properties? I think it's important to understand my answer that you should know it.

Comment: @Crostul:  Unfortunately, I don't know it.  But I can study up on it.  I am very interested in knowing the answer to my question.  If you want to answer, you could take for granted that I know it, but I'd prefer an explanation of it, too - perhaps just a good link to a site or book.  I hope that I'm not asking too much.  I am very interested in the answer, and I'm willing to do some studying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove Fermat's little theorem one can use the fact that the ring $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ is a finite field for all primes $p$. Now, if we are going to deal with numbers of the form $a+bi  \mod{p}$, we have to introduce the ring of numbers of the form $a+bi$ and to quotient by some relation "$\mod{p}$".

Now, let $\mathbb{Z}[i] = \{ a+bi : a, b \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ be the ring of Gaussian Integers. This ring has the nice property that it is a PID and it extends the usual ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}$. Moreover, if $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is a natural number, then the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(n)$ is a finite ring with $n^2$ elements.

Since $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a PID, one can define divisibility relation on it, prime numbers, and unique prime factorization still holds.

Now, one can prove (I will not post the proof) the following theorem: if $p \in \mathbb{N}$ is a prime number, then the following are equivalent:

1. $p = a^2 + b^2$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$
2. $p=2$ or $p \equiv 1 \mod{4}$

this means that if $p\equiv 1 \mod{4}$, then it can be factorized in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ as $p= a^2 + b^2 = (a+bi)(a-bi)$, so that $p$ is not prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ (for completeness note that $2 = (1+i)(1-i)$ )!

Moreover one can also show that in the other case (i.e. $p \equiv 3 \mod{4}$) the number $p$ remains prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

So finally, fixed a prime $p \in \mathbb{N}$ we can consider the ring of numbers of the form $a+bi$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. This is just the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(p)$, which has, as I said above, $p^2$ elements.

In the case that $p \equiv 3 \mod{4}$, this ring is the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ with $p^2$ elements, since $p$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Since the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}^*$ is cyclic of order $p^2-1$, we have that some numbers $n = a+bi \mod{p}$ have $p^2-1$ different powers, i.e. $1, n, n^2, \dots, n^{p^2-2}$ are all 
distinct. These are precisely those numbers which generate the whole group $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}^*$, and the number of them is $\varphi( p^2-1)$, where  $\varphi$ denotes Euler's totient function.

In the case $p=2$ we have a ring with 4 elements which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$. Here all numbers $n \neq 0$ satisfy $n^2=1$.

In the last case $p \equiv 1 \mod{4}$ the ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(p)$ is not a field, but it is isomorphic to the ring $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/ (x^2+1)$, and there are some zero divisors  (i.e. if $p= a^2+b^2$ then $(a+bi)(a-bi)=0$). In fact in this case there can be nilpotent elements and things can be weird. I'm not so sure on how this last case behaves.

Comment: It took far less studying than I thought, but I'm on shaky ground, due to my limited abstract algebra background.  I believe what I'm after, according to your answer, is the very last case in your answer, because I want to limit the amount of unique elements.  Here's the part that I can't seem to wrap my head around (I may need to ask a second question):  Can each element (in other words, each power of $n$) function as a $(p-1)$th root of unity, given that $p\equiv 1 \bmod 4$?